# How to find out which versions of latex packages and program is being used?

Tags: distributions

I sometimes find people send me a LaTeX file and I cannot compile it. There tends to be two reasons:

1. They are using a different executable (Luatex / pdflatex / etc)
2. They have different package versions, often because we use a different latex distribution or different year of the same distribution.

Is there a (hopefully simple) command I can ask people to run that will store all this information, to increase my chances of reproducing their document at a later date?

Comment: If it's MikTeX would be difficult, as packages are updated "continuously" I think.

Comment: If you add `\listfiles` at the top of your file, the `.log` file will contain a list of used package versions at the end. They could share this with you. But even if you know which packages versions people have, obtaining the exact same versions can be quite tricky.

Comment: your title asks for which tex distrbution for which the banner at the top of the log gives the answer,eg  `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.2)  5 NOV 2022 09:37` is tl2022 from TUG rather than a linux texlive or miktex. Your question asks about package versions, for which see gigiair's answer

Comment: Thanks, you are right I was inconsistent with my request. What I really want to be able to do is increase the chance I can rebuild the document at a later date. I have tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask to add `\listfiles` in the source file and attach the log file. It's up to you to find the information you need, it's all in the log file.